# Django-registration не переопределяется метод register в RegistrationView

Tags: python, django

Создал кастомный класс отнаследованный от RegistrationView:

```
class RegistrationViews(RegistrationView):

    form_class = RegistrationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('django_registration_complete')

    def register(self, form):
        print('+' * 50)
        print(new_user)
        new_user = form.save()
        new_user = authenticate(**{
            User.USERNAME_FIELD: new_user.get_username(),
            'password': form.cleaned_data['password1']
        })
        print('-' * 50)
        login(self.request, new_user)
        signals.user_registered.send(
            sender=self.__class__,
            user=new_user,
            request=self.request
        )
        print('*' * 50)
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        print(form.cleaned_data['email'])
        return new_user
```

Для проверки насовал принтов, ни один не выводится в консоль при регистрации.
Причем регистрация работает как с переопределенным методом register, так и без него.

Comment: Уверены, что используете ваш `RegistrationViews` в урле, вместо стандартного?

Comment: Спасибо, ваш комментарий помог разрешить мою проблему!

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, проблема была в том что в url-диспатчере у меня было вот так:

`path('accounts/', include('django_registration.backends.one_step.urls')),
path('accounts/register/', RegistrationViews.as_view(), name='django_registration_register'),`

Поменял их местами и все заработало.